# Marklogic How to save multiple Workspaces

Tags: marklogic

I have multiple Workspaces in Marklogic Qconsole.  How can I export all workspaces at once. Instead of export one workspace at a time to computer.  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your workspaces are saved in the ***App-Services*** database. They have a `qconsole:workspace` element, and will have a `qconsole:userid` element with your userid.

Using some of the built-in functions that are used to generate the export by the QConsole application, you can transform the workspace into the export format.

Below is a query that you can run to find all of your workspaces, generate the export format, and then save them to the `/tmp` directory on the server:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace qconsole="http://marklogic.com/appservices/qconsole";
import module namespace qconsole-model="http://marklogic.com/appservices/qconsole/model" 
  at "/MarkLogic/appservices/qconsole/qconsole-model.xqy";
import module namespace amped-qconsole = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/qconsole/util-amped" 
  at "/MarkLogic/appservices/qconsole/qconsole-amped.xqy";

xdmp:invoke-function(
  function(){
    let $workspaces := cts:search(/qconsole:workspace, 
                         cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("qconsole:userid"), 
                           string(xdmp:get-current-userid())))
    for $workspace in $workspaces
    let $name := $workspace/qconsole:name/string()
    let $wsid := $workspace/qconsole:id/data()
    let $export := qconsole-model:export-workspace($wsid)
    return 
      xdmp:save("/tmp/"||$name||".xml", $export)
  },
  <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
    <database>{xdmp:database("App-Services")}</database>
  </options>
)
```